# What type of unix commands can I use to capture the permissions from "ls -ld" and output it in a certain format?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to figure out which command can capture the permissions outputted from "ls -ld" to be displayed like this:

Example (Assume that I have the header already implemented):

```
  Owner Group Other
  ----- ----- -----
d r w x r w - r - -
```

I'm still brand new and used to have delimiters as a factor, but I'm a bit stuck here since there are none.

EDIT:
I can capture the first column with now with:

```
ls -ld / | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: This might help: `stat --printf "%A\n" .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you're after (I've omitted `/` from the `ls` in my example)

```
ls -ld | awk '{print $1}' | sed -r 's/(.)/ \1/g'
```

The additional sed command captures each character from the output of awk and prepends a space before it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! However, can i ask what '\1/ g' is doing specifically?

Comment: Hi Andrew! No worries. I'll break it down for you: `s/`: start substitution, `(.)` capture single characters into group 1, `/ \1` replace with space and group 1 captured group (called a backreference with sed), `/g` end expression and set the global replace flag, which means it will operate over the whole of the input... :-)

Comment: I appreciate your thorough explanation. Thanks again!

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Great link Cyrus, thanks for bringing that into play. Your stat option is better for sure and I'll happily concede I should've thought more about the flexibility of the soluton! Every day  is a schoolday!!! ;-)